# Setting the DYLD_IMAGE_SUFFIX environment variable to _debug causes crash before main() is called after having updated Lion to 10.7.3

Tags: xcode, frameworks, osx-lion, corruption, foundation

I'm using Xcode 4.1 in Lion 10.7.3 and have edited my project's scheme such that the DYLD_IMAGE_SUFFIX environment variable is set to _debug. This used to work fine, but the 10.7.3 OS X update seems to have duff system Frameworks, which means I cannot even get as far as main() before the app dies. I'm compiling with GCC, and have already tried repairing the OS, re-installing the OS (twice), re-installing Xcode and repairing disk permissions, all to no avail. This also happens in the latest version of Xcode (4.3) in a Cocoa app with absolutely no code in it.

I have the following information in my output window:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _sandbox_extension_update_file
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
```

Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Comment: DYLD_IMAGE_SUFFIX=_debug doesn't work on Lion anyway. They stopped providing debug builds of the frameworks in Snow Leopard; I hear it's some kind of technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem with Gatekeeper enabled under OS X 10.7.4.  Turning off Gatekeeper using:

sudo spctl --master-disable

Fixed the problem.